# How to add AD Group to SP Group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, groups

Just want to know if it is possible to add AD Group to any custom SP Group? by using interface or by using powershell?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an AD group to a SharePoint group, so long as it is a security group, distribution lists will **not** work. You can add them to a group via Powershell or the web UI.